# I can not compile database

Tags: ms-access, compilation

[image]Problem: When user open the split database they get an error telling that the VBA code is bad. If they proceed the codes in the modules get wiped out. Based on what I have read, I need to compile the database but I am stuck! How do I fix the issue below

```
Private Sub Sub_Location_GotFocus()
Dim Location_Filter As Variant
Location_Filter = Me.Location
Me.Sub_Location.RowSource = "SELECT Sub_Location.Sub_Location" _
                            & " FROM Sub_Location" _
                            & " WHERE (((Sub_Location.Location) = '" & Location_Filter & "'))" _
                            & " ORDER BY Sub_Location.Sub_Location;"
End Sub
```

Comment: Try with `Me!Sub_Location.RowSource` or run a _Compact and Repair_ of the database.

Comment: Use of `!` shouldn't make any difference in this code performance. It just will not provoke intellisense tips.